# Getting module not found for all the 11.0 components. They are all defined ad for Root on my shared module. Any ideas?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Angular 16.1.4
Ngx-bootatrap 11.0
Defined on shared module only as forRoot()

All errors similar to
Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown'

Ng serve receives compile errors on seal phase

Only changes was to add forRoot.
Works on Angular 15 branch.

Answer (score 0):

@JasonWeinzierl posted separately that the node-modeles/ngx-bootstrap/package.json

Has the wrong directory listed.

Change fesm2020 to fesm2022

Compiled for me.

Other issues, but this one seems solved for the question I posted.

Comment: Where did you chenge fesm2020 to fesm2022?