# How to fix: { SomeModule } does not appear to be a NgModule Class (-996002)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

After I downgraded my angular application from Angular 16 to angular 11.2.14 I got errors with importing my modules into app.component.ts with NgModule. **Every** module inside `imports: []` is giving me this error.

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { OktaAuthModule } from '@okta/okta-angular';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { GuestFormComponent } from './guest-form/guest-form.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { ReturningUserComponent } from './returning-user/returning-user.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    GuestFormComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    ReturningUserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OktaAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "jenkinsbuild": "npm install; ng --version; ng build --configuration=config",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run test:test --prefix ../",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^5.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

I've already tried different things that I've found in other stackoverflow posts and blogs to fix it such as:

- deleting my `node_modules` and running `npm install` after,
- running ng update, disabling Ivy,
- adding `"postinstall": "ngcc"` to `package.json`

Nothing that I have tried so far has worked.

Does anyone know what I should do to fix it?

Comment: this is a bug from current ngx-bootstrap version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665760/getting-module-not-found-for-all-the-11-0-components-they-are-all-defined-ad-fo

Answer (score 0):

a new version will be released soon : https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/6599

Comment: Add more context to your answers helps the requestor to understand your answer more accurately.